# Two independent groups and three dependent variables

Tags: anova, multivariate-analysis, manova

How do I test for differences between two groups on three dependent variables? Is that an ANOVA or multiple t-tests with an adjusted alpha level?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into the *Multivariate*-ANOVA (called MANOVA).  I'm not sure about good internet-based resources; the Wikipedia page is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_analysis_of_variance), and the entry in StatSoft's online textbook is [here](http://www.statsoft.com/Textbook/ANOVA-MANOVA#multivariate), but neither seem great.  For a 'real' textbook that is more or less math-free, [Tabachnick & Fidell](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0205849571) is the most popular.  If you use SPSS, SAS, or Stata, the excellent UCLA statistics help site has some quick tutorials; they can be found [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/dae/).